# Why is the default for @task.docker autoremove = False

Tags: airflow

We use docker operators via @task.docker decorator/Taskflow in airflow to run most of our tasks. We have had issues with docker containers not exiting correctly, and taking up memory, which eventually stops new containers from being able to be spun up. It looks like this is because we haven't set the per task parameter autoremove=True.

I'm interested if anyone can help me understand why we would not want default behaviour to be docker images exiting after running the task?

My current hypothesis is that perhaps we can reuse running containers the next time we need, so getting rid of a small startup time?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like Airflow has implemented the defaults that align with Docker itself. From the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#clean-up---rm):

> By default a container's file system persists even after the container
> exits. This makes debugging a lot easier (since you can inspect the
> final state) and you retain all your data by default. But if you are
> running short-term foreground processes, these container file systems
> can really pile up. If instead you'd like Docker to automatically
> clean up the container and remove the file system when the container
> exits, you can add the --rm flag

In an airflow context, uses may vary, but certainly in our data pipeline we are running many short running foreground processes, and once in production (unless we have issues) there is no need to hold onto the container. In fact, in our case we had these stacking up so much that it clogged up our machine and stopped running jobs.

My recommendation is that in dev airflow, run auto_remove=False (the default) on @task.docker, but in production set it to True.